# ValueError: "<Task: Task object>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

## Problem Description

I have 2 models that have a many to one relationship (There can be 1-many Tasks per Event), so I have set up a reverse ForeignKey relationship with a related name as you'll see below. I want to be able to create one or more of those tasks on POST of an Event, so I am using nested serializers as shown in the [documentation for writable nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for Django Rest Framework (I've used this method with great success in the past).

I can create a Task without any difficulty and I can create an Event without problems (with `tasks=[]`).

The problem is that this time, for whatever reason, if I nest the exact same payload I am using to create a Task into the `tasks` array, I get the following error: `ValueError: "<Task: Task object>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`.

**This is confusing for several reasons:**

1. The TaskSerializer accepts the payload on its own to create a new Task.
2. The Event actually gets created, but with `tasks=[]`
3. Events and Tasks is not a many-to-many relationship, so it must be erroring on `assignees`, but I'm just giving it an array of primary keys, not objects. And again, it works when just POST to create a new Task.
4. Running the commands from `views.py` line by line shows that `serializer.is_valid()` returns `True`, but upon `serializer.save()`, I receive an error (full error shown below).

## Models/Views/Serializers

**Event model**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, null=True, related_name='calendar_events')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name='calendar_events')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    invitees = models.ManyToManyField(ExtendedUser, default=[], blank=True, related_name='events_invited')
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    stop = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    frequency = models.ForeignKey(Frequency, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    recurring = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    all_day = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Administrative Fields
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Task model**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, null=True, related_name='tasks')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name='tasks')
    assignees = models.ManyToManyField(ExtendedUser, default=[], blank=True, related_name='tasks_assigned')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
    type = models.ForeignKey(TaskType, null=True, default=None)
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, null=True, default=None)
    data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    completed_by = models.ForeignKey(ExtendedUser, null=True, blank=True, default=None, related_name='task_completed')
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, null=True, default=None, related_name='task')
    # Optionally, a task can be connected to an Event or Workflow
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, default=None, related_name='tasks')
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow, null=True, default=None, related_name='tasks')
    # Administrative Fields
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Task view for GET/POST**

```
class UserTaskListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsCurrentUserOrAgentOrDeveloper]
    serializer_class = TaskDetailSerializer
    pagination_class = Pagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_slug = self.kwargs['user_slug']
        return Task.objects.filter(
            Q(owner__slug=user_slug) | Q(assignees__slug=user_slug)
        )

    def create(self, request, user_slug):
        request.data['owner'] = ExtendedUser.objects.get(slug=user_slug).id

        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):

            serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**Event view for POST**

```
class UserScheduleListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsCurrentUserOrAgentOrDeveloper]
    serializer_class = EventDetailSerializer
    pagination_class = Pagination

    def create(self, request, user_slug):
        request.data['owner'] = ExtendedUser.objects.get(slug=user_slug).id

    serializer = EventSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):

        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**Task Serializer**

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = SiteField()
    data = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = [
            'id',
            'owner',
            'site',
            'assignees',
            'type',
            'title',
            'description',
            'template',
            'data',
            'completed',
            'completed_at',
            'completed_by',
            'priority',
            'event',
            'workflow',
            'created',
            'updated'
        ]
```

**Event Serializer**

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = SiteField()
    tasks = TaskSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            'id',
            'owner',
            'site',
            'title',
            'description',
            'invitees',
            'start',
            'stop',
            'frequency',
            'recurring',
            'all_day',
            'tasks',
            'created',
            'updated'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        invitees = validated_data.pop('invitees', None)
        tasks_data = validated_data.pop('tasks', None)

        event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for invitee in invitees:
            event.invitees.add(invitee)

        event.save()

        if tasks_data is not None:
            for task_data in tasks_data:
                task = Task.objects.create(event=event, **task_data)

        return event
```

## Full error output

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4bde7bc40c4c> in <module>()
----> 1 serializer.save()

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in save(self, **kwargs)
    212             )
    213         else:
--> 214             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
    215             assert self.instance is not None, (
    216                 '`create()` did not return an object instance.'

~/Desktop/sandboxes/python/tomis-backend/component/calendar/serializers.py in create(self, validated_data)
     69                 print('event:', event)
     70                 print('task_data:', task_data)
---> 71                 Task.objects.create(event=event, **task_data)
     72                 print('thingy')
     73                 # event.tasks.create(**task_data)

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     83         def create_method(name, method):
     84             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 85                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
     86             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
     87             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in create(self, **kwargs)
    390         and returning the created object.
    391         """
--> 392         obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    393         self._for_write = True
    394         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    566                     if prop in property_names or opts.get_field(prop):
    567                         if kwargs[prop] is not _DEFERRED:
--> 568                             _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
    569                         del kwargs[prop]
    570                 except (AttributeError, FieldDoesNotExist):

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __set__(self, instance, value)
    534             RemovedInDjango20Warning, stacklevel=2,
    535         )
--> 536         manager = self.__get__(instance)
    537         manager.set(value)
    538 

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __get__(self, instance, cls)
    511             return self
    512 
--> 513         return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
    514 
    515     def _get_set_deprecation_msg_params(self):

~/.virtualenvs/tomis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __init__(self, instance)
    828                 raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
    829                                  'this many-to-many relationship can be used.' %
--> 830                                  (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
    831             # Even if this relation is not to pk, we require still pk value.
    832             # The wish is that the instance has been already saved to DB,

ValueError: "<Task: Task object>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like problem is with Task's `assignees` field. Since it's many-to-many, you should save each Task separately before add assignees to it:

```
if tasks_data is not None:
    for task_data in tasks_data:
        assignees = task_data.pop('assignees')
        task = Task.objects.create(event=event, **task_data)
        task.assignees = assignees
        task.save()
```

Comment: Wow, awesome, that totally fixed it! With some minor modifications, which I'll edit your answer for.